# Access Violation Error

Tags: c++, memory, access-violation

Here's the code:

```
void SendRemoteData(string Data){
    char charout[1000];
    memset(charout,0,sizeof(charout));
    memcpy(charout,Data.c_str(),Data.size());
    send(tempclient, charout, sizeof(charout),0);
}
```

When I try to use this function twice, I get the error. What should I do?

Comment: Instead of using `memset`, you can write `char charout[1000] = {};` It will zero-initialize the array.

Comment: Error? what error? Try to check `send` return and check `errno`

Comment: C++? Or C? Pick a language and stick with it (at least per question, but preferably per source file)!

Comment: what you should do is run it through a debugger and get a proper call stack.

Comment: if (Data.size() > sizeof(charout)) panic();

Answer (score 2):

Find out in wich line the access violation happens - there are some positions that might be a problem. As example: you assume that `Data` is always smaller than 1000 characters - otherwise you cause a buffer overrun. Also, you always send 1000 bytes - is that really your intention?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
void SendRemoteData(string Data){
    send(tempclient, Data.c_str(), Data.size(),0);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing, the original code always sends 1000 bytes.

Comment: True, the functionality is different, and just maybe what OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured because you can't use a string there in memcpy, but you're using `Data.c_str()`, which is wrong and gives me an error.

A cast should solve the problem:

```
memcpy(charout,(char *)Data.c_str(),Data.size());
```